# Evento em 2 servidores ao mesmo tempo

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou programando um bot para meus servidores no Discord e queria que o evento de Guild Member Add funcionasse em dois servidores ao mesmo tempo.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix } = require('../config.json');

module.exports = async (client, member) => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "preferencial");

    let join = await new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#7c2ae8")
    .setTitle(`Boas-vindas, ${member.user.tag}`)
    .setDescription(`Peça ajuda em ${prefix}help`)
    .setImage("https://imgur.com/KiOx0Za.gif")
    .setTimestamp();
    channel.send(join);
}
```

Como posso fazer a declaração para funcionar em outro servidor?
Estou usando discord.js

Answer (score 2):

Esse evento funciona para todos os servidores em que o `bot` está,um exemplo do código que eu estou usando no meu bot, e que funciona perfeitamente:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    var welcomeEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle(`**Welcome to the server ${member.user.username}**`)
    .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL())
    member.guild.channels.cache.get('Identificação do canal onde será enviada a mensagem aqui').send(welcomeEmbed)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Esse evento funciona em todos os servidores que o bot está!
Se você quer definir uma mensagem diferente para cada servidor, uma das maneiras que você pode usar é um `banco de dados local`, pra isso existem vários pacotes disponíveis! Um que eu recomendo muito por ser facil de mexer é o [secure-db](https://npmjs.com/package/secure-db).

Exemplo:

```js
const db = require('secure-db');

db.set('id_do_servidor1-WELCOME', 'Seja bem-vindo');
db.set('id_do_servidor2-WELCOME', 'Olá, {membro}! Leia as regras e se divirta!');

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    var welcomeEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setDescription(db.get(`${member.guild.id}-WELCOME`));

    member.guild.channels.cache.get('ID DO CANAL').send(welcomeEmbed)
});
```